# Cherrypy json_out module error in Ubuntu

Tags: python, json, cherrypy

I am trying to get Cherrypy to output json for a project and on my Mac adding the @cherrpy.tools.json_out() decorator is working a treat but on my Ubuntu 13.04 system I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cherrypy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cherrypy
  File "/bla/cherrypy.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Root(object):
  File "/bla/cherrypy.py", line 6, in Root
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tools'
```

The code above is a direct copy from the bottom of this page.
http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/JSON

If i enter a python shell then run interactive help on the module I get a similar result.

```
help> cherrypy
problem in cherrypy - <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute 'tools'
```

I have tried searching but I can't find anyone else having the same issue? (Maybe I am missing the wood for the trees?)

I have tried reinstalling the package through apt and manually from the cherrypy source all against Python 2.7

Although I am developing on Mac and Ubuntu I will be deploying on an Ubuntu server so I would like to sort this out sooner rather than later.

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use `python-cherrypy` from ubuntu package? It's version is 2.3.0 which does not have `cherrypy.tools` modules.

Install newer version (`sudo pip install -U cherrypy`).

Comment: I tried python-cherrypy and python-cherrypy3 before removing both and installing from the cherrypy tarball direct from the cherrypy site. I haven't tried to install through pip yet, I'll try that later today.